# Having an error here in react.js on using Array,map() while window.onload

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am a noobie to react and i was creating a project on calculator in react.
i wanted to display the buttons by having the button automatically inserted from a given function like
`const ids=["zero","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","equals","add","subtract","multiply","divide","decimal","clear"];`
and i wanted to have buttons on an array test like
`const test=[<button id={ids[0]}></button>];` 
all this wanna happen on window load
so i tried to map the button to array on window load like

```
window.onload=function (){
   test.map((obj,i,ids)=>{return (<button id={ids[obj]}></button>)});
}
```

but the array **test** isn't getting updated
can anyone help me with it
all i wanted is to create  the buttons when the page load by the above code,so that i can reduce the code rather than typing each code for each button which in turn affects speed

Comment: Where is this `window.onload` code? I think you are mixing up jsx syntax with vanilla js DOM manipulation. `jsx` syntax is not valid javascript. It gets transpiled to javascript.

Comment: You also should be doing `test = test.map()`, `.map` returns a new, altered array afaik

Comment: @adiga 1)i used the window.onload right after the above 2 declaration,2)what should i do to get the transpiled script correct